# How to scrape an API response that is requested by the target website?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'd like to scrape content of a website that is requested asynchronous and not visible in the source code.

How can I await the website's request? I need to sniff its traffic somehow, but couldn't find anything yet.

I'm looking something like that (pseudo code):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("http://target.tld")
traffic = page.sniff_traffic(seconds=10)
for req in traffic:
    print(req)  # http://api.target.tld

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with BeautifulSoup, you need to use something which mimics a web browser, such as Selenium with Geckodriver.

Comment: Thanks for leading me in the right direction!